# Android Profiler: always show "no cpu usage data available for this imported trace"

Tags: android, profiler

I captured the trace file using Debug.startMethodTracing and Debug.stopMethodTracing. This worked fine, I got the .trace file. But when I opened it in the Android Studio Profiler tool, it always show "no cpu usage data available for this imported trace", like below
[image]

I'm using the Android Studio 4.0